# How to Add 30 days to 1st Datepicker, display it on the 2nd Datepicker. And Add 3 days to 2nd , display it on 3rd?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Am new to jQuery and JavaScript. So please help me solve my problem.

Am able to add days with two datepicker. But what i want is take days from 3 datepickers and display it on a 4th datepicker. I would like to know the solution for this!.

My code is :)

```
<p>Date:
    <input id="txtDate" type="text" />
</p>

<p>
    <input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Fill Follow Date" />
</p>

<p>Date:
    <input id="follow_Date" type="text" />
</p>

<p>
    <input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Fill Follow DateOne" />
</p>
<p>Date:
    <input id="follow_Date_One" type="text" />
</p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtDate').datepicker();
    $('#follow_Date').datepicker();
    $('#follow_Date_One').datepicker();
});

function getdate() {
    var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;

    var date = new Date(tt);
    var newdate = new Date(date);

    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 30);

    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
    document.getElementById('follow_Date').value = someFormattedDate;

    var rr = document.getElementById('follow_Date').value;

    var dateOne = new Date(rr);
    var newdateOne = new Date(dateOne);

    newdateOne.setDate(newdateOne.getDate() + 3);

    ar dd = newdateOne.getDate();
    var mm = newdateOne.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = newdateOne.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDateOne = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
    document.getElementById('follow_Date_One').value = someFormattedDateOne;



}
</script>
</form>
```

What am doing here is, I take the Date from the First `Datepicker` and when I click on the button `Fill Follow Date`,  `30` will be added to the current day and displayed in the second `Datepicker`, this i am able to do it.

Now i want to take the second `Datepicker` `day` and add `3` to it and display it on the third Datepicker, when i click the button `Fill Follow DateOne`. Am not able to do the second part. Please help me with your logic. 
Sorry, if my logic is completely wrong:>

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: @AlonEitan, sorry, i didn't post my code at first. Now i have posted, pls have a look. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code on both button click you are calling the same function,add two separate functions for these button clicks.It will work fine.

**Try this code**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#txtDate').datepicker();
$('#follow_Date').datepicker();
$('#follow_Date_One').datepicker();

$('input[id="follow_Date_btn"]').on('click',function(){
var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
 if(!tt==""){
var date = new Date(tt);
var newdate = new Date(date);

newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 30);

var dd = newdate.getDate();
var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
var y = newdate.getFullYear();

var someFormattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
document.getElementById('follow_Date').value = someFormattedDate;
} else {
alert("enter date");
}
});
  $('input[id="follow_Date_One_btn"]').on('click',function(){
var rr = document.getElementById('follow_Date').value;
if(!rr==""){
var dateOne = new Date(rr);
var newdateOne = new Date(dateOne);

newdateOne.setDate(newdateOne.getDate() + 3);

var dd = newdateOne.getDate();
var mm = newdateOne.getMonth() + 1;
var y = newdateOne.getFullYear();

var someFormattedDateOne = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
document.getElementById('follow_Date_One').value = someFormattedDateOne;
    } else {
alert("enter date");
}
  });
});
```

```css
   .Highlighted a {
    background-color: Red !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    color: White !important;
}
.block{
  width:calc(100%/4 - 10px);
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
}
 .block>input {
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<p>Date:
<input id="txtDate" type="text" />
</p>

<p>
<input type="button" id="follow_Date_btn" value="Fill Follow Date" />
</p>

<p>Date:
<input id="follow_Date" type="text" />
</p>

<p>
<input type="button" id="follow_Date_One_btn" value="Fill Follow DateOne" />
</p>
<p>Date:
<input id="follow_Date_One" type="text" />
</p>
```

Comment: Hi @Amal Thanks for the response. But your code is not working!!. Please have look at my code.

Comment: @basavaraj_gowda Glad to help you

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. Please explain what the solution you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.